# How can I optimize my Travis CI matrix for Django and Python versions?

Tags: python, django, travis-ci

I have a .travis.yml file that looks like this:

https://gist.github.com/dyve/d79e5cd4f81bb2675181

(original: https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3/blob/develop/.travis.yml)

I have to type several Python and Django versions more than once. I would like to:

- Automatically pick the newest Django 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 and 1.7
- Exclude Python>2 && Django<1.6
- Exclude Python<2.7 && Django>1.6

Is there a more DRY way to do this in a Travis CI file?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a matrix in your .travis.yml file with Python and Django versions. Here is an example [.travis.yml](https://github.com/gracenote/django-health-monitor/blob/master/.travis.yml) that I am using.

You can also tell Travis CI to install the latest version of Django up to a certain release by using something similar to the following. Note that `Django<1.11` will install the latest 1.10.x release.

`matrix:
   - DJANGO="Django<1.8"
   - DJANGO="Django<1.9"
   - DJANGO="Django<1.10"
   - DJANGO="Django<1.11"
   - DJANGO="Django<1.12"`

Also, note that not all combinations need to pass and not all combinations are officially supported. A list of Python/Django combinations that should be covered can be found in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django).

Exclusions can be handled using something similar to the following:

`matrix:
  exclude:
    - python: "3.5"
      env: DJANGO="Django<1.8"`